# Angular PUT request pending for ever

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, symfony, cors, fosrestbundle

I am developing an application with an Angular front-end (based on Yeoman) and a Symfony 2, FOSRestBundle back-end. When I send a PUT request (or POST request for that matter) it holds the status pending for ever. I'm using CORS and all headers are set correct. The preflight OPTIONS request also has the correct headers and is handled correct.

[Chrome developer tools PUT request] => https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkCtL.png

When I check the PUT request with XDEBUG in the back-end the request is processed correct by the server and the server sends a correct response to the front-end.

[XDEBUG info in back-end] => https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5EBI.png

When I follow the request in the front-end by setting a break-point and stepping through the code it never reaches the `.then` methond from the promise.

The code from the controller is:

```
/**
 * Will create a reservation for a single availability (exact + intersect)
 *
 * @param   Object availabilities
 */
$scope.createReservationSingle = function(availabilities)
{
    var availability = availabilities[0],
        id = availability.id,
        parkingspace = availability.parkingspace_id,
        reservationstart = moment($scope.request.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
        reservationend = moment($scope.request.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
        requeststart = moment(availability.requeststart).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
        requestend = moment(availability.requestend).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
        user = availability.user_id,
        data = { 'guest' : $scope.user.id,
            'user': user,
            'parkingspace': parkingspace,
            'requeststart': requeststart,
            'requestend': requestend,
            'reservationstart': reservationstart,
            'reservationend' : reservationend,
            'yield' : $scope.request.points,
            'status' : '1'
        };
        console.log(data);

        Reservation.createReservation(id, data).then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }, function(reason) {
            console.log('ReservationsCtrl::createRequest', 'ERROR', reason);
        });

};
```

The code from the service is:

```
/**
 * Updates a request to a reservation by adding the start- and end datetime, guest_id and points.
 *
 * @param data
 * @returns {promise}
 */
var createReservation = function(id, data)
{
    var deferred = $q.defer(),
        url = "/api/v1/reservations/"+ parseInt(id) +".json";

    $http.put(url, data).success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.reject);
    console.log(deferred.promise);
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I'm really confused and stuck here, when I ran (almost the exact code) without CORS enabled (from the same domain, so no need for CORS) and without Yeoman it ran correct and the PUT and POST request were correctly returned from the server and correctly recieved by the front-end application.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

UPDATE:
On suggestion of @sebbo I checked the log at app/dev/dev.log:

```
[2014-08-29 08:25:16] event.DEBUG: Listener "FOS\RestBundle\EventListener\ViewResponseListener::onKernelView" stopped propagation of the event "kernel.view". [] []
[2014-08-29 08:25:16] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Nelmio\CorsBundle\EventListener\CorsListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-29 08:25:16] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-29 08:25:16] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ChromePhpHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-29 08:25:16] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "FOS\RestBundle\EventListener\AllowedMethodsListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-29 08:25:16] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-29 08:25:16] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-29 08:25:16] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\CacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-29 08:25:16] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-29 08:25:17] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-29 08:25:17] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-29 08:25:17] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
```

Not special happens here I guess... :'(

Just to be sure I also checked the Apache access- and error-log.

Apache access-log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2014:08:24:37 +0200] "GET /oauth/v2/token?client_id=3_2r03j9282aecks0c488owcko4w8gkc8w800kog4w8gw0g8ck0w&client_secret=1elz2h57nyiscwg04k8gccsskscsc4g88sccosk0sc0ogwg48s&grant_type=password&username=ashtonwenzel&password=ashtonwenzel HTTP/1.1" 200 265
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2014:08:24:39 +0200] "GET /api/v1/users/current.json?access_token=MjgyZDBiZjgyNDBiZDNjYTJjNzkxYzJiZjk3OWZkOWU5ZGUzODYzYmVmMDYxMWRmOTg3ODdhOWE4MTQwMzcwYg&XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM HTTP/1.1" 200 643
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2014:08:24:58 +0200] "GET /api/v1/users/5/availabilities/search.json?start=2014-08-29%2008:30&end=2014-08-29%2008:45&access_token=MjgyZDBiZjgyNDBiZDNjYTJjNzkxYzJiZjk3OWZkOWU5ZGUzODYzYmVmMDYxMWRmOTg3ODdhOWE4MTQwMzcwYg&XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM HTTP/1.1" 200 181
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2014:08:25:12 +0200] "OPTIONS /api/v1/reservations/9040.json?access_token=MjgyZDBiZjgyNDBiZDNjYTJjNzkxYzJiZjk3OWZkOWU5ZGUzODYzYmVmMDYxMWRmOTg3ODdhOWE4MTQwMzcwYg&XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2014:08:25:12 +0200] "PUT /api/v1/reservations/9040.json?access_token=MjgyZDBiZjgyNDBiZDNjYTJjNzkxYzJiZjk3OWZkOWU5ZGUzODYzYmVmMDYxMWRmOTg3ODdhOWE4MTQwMzcwYg&XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM HTTP/1.1" 204 360374
```

Apache error-log:

Only had some stuff I added manually by using the `error_log` function from within PHP.

Still completely stuck, to whomever who reads this, I could really, really need some suggestions on where to look... :)

UPDATE 2:

Here are the details of the OPTIONS and the PUT requests.

OPTIONS:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Request URL:http://develop.prs.nl/api/v1/reservations/6514.json?access_token=ZDQxODJkNDFmZTNhNTBjMTQ0OTE1MjlmZTcyOWMzZGUxNjViNDA4NjZlM2QxMThmNDdiMzIwODJiMTQ0MDU1Zg&XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6,nl;q=0.4,sq;q=0.2
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:PUT
Connection:keep-alive
Host:develop.prs.nl
Origin:http://frontend.prs.nl
Referer:http://frontend.prs.nl/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
access_token:ZDQxODJkNDFmZTNhNTBjMTQ0OTE1MjlmZTcyOWMzZGUxNjViNDA4NjZlM2QxMThmNDdiMzIwODJiMTQ0MDU1Zg
XDEBUG_SESSION_START:PHPSTORM
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:origin, content-type, accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://frontend.prs.nl
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 29 Aug 2014 13:50:58 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.24 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
Set-Cookie:XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM; expires=Fri, 29-Aug-2014 14:50:58 GMT; path=/
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Debug-Token:ac1b50
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.24
```

PUT:

```
Request URL:http://develop.prs.nl/api/v1/reservations/6514.json?access_token=ZDQxODJkNDFmZTNhNTBjMTQ0OTE1MjlmZTcyOWMzZGUxNjViNDA4NjZlM2QxMThmNDdiMzIwODJiMTQ0MDU1Zg&XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://frontend.prs.nl
Referer:http://frontend.prs.nl/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:DC58FE79-4B4C-689A-A632-B5886576FACC
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
access_token:ZDQxODJkNDFmZTNhNTBjMTQ0OTE1MjlmZTcyOWMzZGUxNjViNDA4NjZlM2QxMThmNDdiMzIwODJiMTQ0MDU1Zg
XDEBUG_SESSION_START:PHPSTORM
Request Payloadview source
{guest:5, user:41, parkingspace:42, requeststart:2014-08-29 14:30:00, requestend:2014-08-29 20:00:00,…}
guest: 5
parkingspace: "42"
requestend: "2014-08-29 20:00:00"
requeststart: "2014-08-29 14:30:00"
reservationend: "2014-08-29 16:15:00"
reservationstart: "2014-08-29 16:00:00"
status: "1"
user: "41"
yield: 1
```

To me, after some thorough investigation about CORS et all, the headers on the requests look fine. But... still completely lost.

Tonight when I have some more time, I'll create a PUT request with pure jQuery (juk!) to check if the problem resides in the front-end (or Angular) or in the back-end (although the Symfony/Apache logs tell me otherwise).

If someone has any other suggestions, they're welcome!

UPDATE II:

Still not able to figure out what is going wrong. I have placed the front-end on the exact same domain as the back-end, and then it works. So I suspect something with CORS... :'( (see comments)

Maybe someone who has experience with either the NelmioCorsBundle or FOSRestBundle could take a look at the configurations I pasted below:

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            xml:  true
            json: true
        templating_formats:
            html: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: ^/, priorities: [ html, json, xml ], fallback_format: ~, prefer_extension: true }
    exception:
        codes:
            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': 404
            'Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException': HTTP_CONFLICT
        messages:
            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': true
    allowed_methods_listener: true
    access_denied_listener:
        json: true
    body_listener: true
    disable_csrf_role: ROLE_API

nelmio_cors:
    paths:
        '^/':
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['X-Requested-With', 'Origin', 'Content-Type', 'Accept']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'PATCH', 'OPTIONS']
            max_age: 3600
```

After this the headers for the OPTIONS request are:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Request URL:http://develop.prs.nl/api/v1/reservations/12649.json?access_token=MDNmMjM5OWQzOGZmODMzYjk3MWRmNWRhNDBiNTMxMjRiOTI3YzNkYTU2MTJmMTcyMDI5MTZkZjBmOGM3MTVkMg&XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6,nl;q=0.4,sq;q=0.2
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:PUT
Connection:keep-alive
Host:develop.prs.nl
Origin:http://localhost:9001
Referer:http://localhost:9001/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
access_token:MDNmMjM5OWQzOGZmODMzYjk3MWRmNWRhNDBiNTMxMjRiOTI3YzNkYTU2MTJmMTcyMDI5MTZkZjBmOGM3MTVkMg
XDEBUG_SESSION_START:PHPSTORM
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-requested-with, origin, content-type, accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:9001
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 02 Sep 2014 19:24:53 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.24 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
Set-Cookie:XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM; expires=Tue, 02-Sep-2014 20:24:53 GMT; path=/
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Debug-Token:83c356
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.24
```

And I'm still not having any clue... :'(

UPDATE III:

I just tried to do a request by Curl. And that works, which is actually not good news I guess since I still don;t know why the request made by the browser (both Chrome and Firefox) keep having a pending state.

The Curl request I made:

```
curl 'http://develop.prs.nl/api/v1/reservations/20884.json?access_token=MDNmMjM5OWQzOGZmODMzYjk3MWRmNWRhNDBiNTMxMjRiOTI3YzNkYTU2MTJmMTcyMDI5MTZkZjBmOGM3MTVkMg&XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM' -X PUT -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Referer: http://develop.prs.nl:9001/' -H 'Origin: http://develop.prs.nl:9001' -H 'X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id: 03571AFA-71C5-867C-1258-3F1D8EC4F8EF' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' --data-binary '{"guest":5,"user":"129","parkingspace":"156","requeststart":"2014-09-02 16:00:00","requestend":"2014-12-31 21:00:00","reservationstart":"2014-09-02 21:30:00","reservationend":"2014-09-02 21:45:00","yield":1,"status":"1"}' --compressed -vvv > curl_log.txt
```

The output of the Curl reuqets on screen:

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7faca300c400
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7faca300c400) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to develop.prs.nl port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to develop.prs.nl (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> PUT /api/v1/reservations/20884.json?access_token=MDNmMjM5OWQzOGZmODMzYjk3MWRmNWRhNDBiNTMxMjRiOTI3YzNkYTU2MTJmMTcyMDI5MTZkZjBmOGM3MTVkMg&XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM HTTP/1.1
> Host: develop.prs.nl
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
> Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
> Referer: http://develop.prs.nl:9001/
> Origin: http://develop.prs.nl:9001
> X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id: 03571AFA-71C5-867C-1258-3F1D8EC4F8EF
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36
> Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
> Content-Length: 220
> 
} [data not shown]
* upload completely sent off: 220 out of 220 bytes
100   220    0     0  100   220      0     54  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--    54< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 02 Sep 2014 19:34:44 GMT
* Server Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.24 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.24 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.24
< Set-Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM; expires=Tue, 02-Sep-2014 20:34:44 GMT; path=/
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://develop.prs.nl:9001
< X-ChromeLogger-Data: 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
< Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
< X-Debug-Token: a4f9cf
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: application/json
< 
{ [data not shown]
100  352k    0  351k  100   220  87534     53  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:-- 87555
* Connection #0 to host develop.prs.nl left intact
```

And the output of the .txt file to which I've piped the result is just correct. And when I check the database all data has been changed according to my expectations.

Conclusion for now, Curl works correct, Chrome and Firefox still have a pending state on the PUT request after the inflight OPTIONS request. Really, really, really lost...

UPDATE IV:

Finally solved it! And how f&%*ing simple was it. When riding my bike it thought of the Nelmio Cors Budnle configuration and when I got home I made a small change:

```
nelmio_cors:
    paths:
        '^/':
            allow_credentials: true
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['X-Requested-With', 'X-Prototype-Version', 'Cache-Control', 'Pragma', 'Origin', 'Content-Type', 'Accept']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'PATCH', 'OPTIONS']
            expose_headers: ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']
            max_age: 3600
```

And presto, it works! So adding the expose headers part in the Nelmio Cors Bundle configuration just did the trick. LOL

Beers!!! :)

Comment: Did you check your symfony dev log? Xdebug may show that the data is returned but maybe something else goes wrong afterwards. Another idea - does your response contain valid JSON data?

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks! I checked the log at app/dev/dev.log, but I didn't see anything strange:

Comment: Updated the description with an excerpt of app/dev/dev.log and the Apache access-log.

Comment: That's really strange -.- Could you maybe also upload the response of the options request and the details of the PUT request from the developer toolbar?

Comment: Sure, will add another update. Thanks for replying!

Comment: Super weird... from my point of view everything looks fine. I'm excited to see if you successfully get the response when using simple jQuery.

Comment: Wow, the jQuery PUT didn't work out. So I did the only thing which I could think of was to move the front-end application to the same domain as the back-end to avoid any potential CORS problems. And, it turns out to be working correct!

I'm totally baffled! I think, when reading about CORS and it's headers, my headers are correct. Even the OPTIONS requests gets a correct reply (as you can read above). Am I missing something or do I need to read up on CORS?

Comment: Hmmm did you try it with a "*" wildcard for the access control allow origin domain?

Comment: Yeah I did. I added it to the .htaccess and to the vhost directive. Both of them did not make any difference. Right now I have fallen back on the NelmioCorsBundle in which I also configured an asterix (then the requesting domain will be returned). Headers again (or still) are looking fine. A colleague of mine suggested to try it with a 'normal' Curl call and adding -vvv for verbose to see what will be logged. When I tried to redo a call by Curl which had been previously send by the browser I ended up with a Doctirne constraint failing. This means that the request had been processed in backend

Comment: I suspect somewhere either in the FosRestBundle or the NelmiocorsBundle something is messing stuff up. I will add the configuration for both these bundles to my original post (too long for here). Maybe someone sees something which isn't right in these configurations... (Still hoping for the best! :))